# Can I have top sliding drawer in Android 2.1?

Tags: android, android-widget, android-animation

I simply want a sliding drawer from top in android which is applicable on Android 2.1.  You can see an example of my need at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2hamed/LstJX/embedded/result/).
Is this possible using `View Animations`?

*Note: The [android misc widgets](http://code.google.com/p/android-misc-widgets/) are useless to me, since they are far from usable in this case!*

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Why don't you just use a sliding drawer?

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SlidingDrawer.html

```
<SlidingDrawer
     android:id="@+id/drawer"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"

     android:handle="@+id/handle"
     android:content="@+id/content">

     <ImageView
         android:id="@id/handle"
         android:layout_width="88dip"
         android:layout_height="44dip" />

     <GridView
         android:id="@id/content"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent" />

 </SlidingDrawer>
```

[Sliding Drawer Google Search](https://www.google.co.uk/search?sugexp=chrome,mod=19&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=android%20sliding%20drawer)

[image]

Comment: Can it be used from top to bottom? I wanted to use it but it does not support Top-to-Bottom direction!

Comment: Yes you can extend it and make it go top to bottom instead of bottom to top! Go search: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1142979/how-to-change-orientation-of-android-slidingdrawer-by-code?rq=1

Comment: `This class was deprecated in API level 17.` The answer was working when I gave it 1.5 years ago ;-)